# Inserting Empty Row into a Excel Document

Tags: perl, ole

I have a excel document that I am editing with perl OLE automation and I have run into a problem. I need to enter an empty row in between two rows that already contain data, kind of like appending it to the file but not at the end of the file. I don't want to have to rewrite the entire file using perl either. How would I go about doing this?

Thanks

Comment: http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=882700

Comment: Thanks, it worked, y don't you put this as an answer?

Comment: Because I didn't really answer the question.  I just found a page that did.

Answer (score 0):

One thing that always helps me when I am automating Excel with Perl & Win32::OLE is to create a macro in Excel capturing exactly what I am trying to accomplish first.  From there I can view the VB code and usually convert that to Perl relatively easily.

For example, in an open Excel 2010 file:

1. View -> Macros -> Record New Macro
2. Click OK
3. Right click somewhere on the sheet to insert a new row
4. View -> Macros -> Stop Recording
5. View -> Macros -> View Macros, click edit

From this, I could write code, for example:

```
#!c:/perl/bin/perl.exe

use strict;
use warnings;

use Win32::OLE;

my $excel = Win32::OLE->new( 'Excel.Application' )
    or die "Could Not Start Excel.\n";
$excel->{ 'Visible' }           = 1;
$excel->{ DisplayAlerts }       = 0;
$excel->{ SheetsInNewWorkBook } = 1;
my $workbook = $excel->Workbooks->Add;
my $sheet = $workbook->Sheets( 1 );

$sheet->Range( 'A1' )->{ Value } = 'Data 1';
$sheet->Range( 'A2' )->{ Value } = 'Data 2';
$sheet->Range( '2:2' )->Select(); #Select Entire 2nd Row
$sheet->Range( '2:2' )->Insert( {
    'Shift'      => -4121, #xlDown
    'CopyOrigin' => 0,     #xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
} );

__END__
```

Also, here is a list of a bunch of the Excel enumerations: http://www.datapigtechnologies.com/downloads/Excel_Enumerations.txt

Hope this helps!